# Как экспортировать svg в pdf (растр) без сохранения в фаил?

Tags: svg, export, файлы, pdf

Как экспортировать svg в pdf (растр) без сохранения в фаил?

Comment: Что не надо сохранять в файл? svg или pdf? И pdf -- обязательно растр?

Comment: Есть: svg сгенерированный ресурс. Промежуточный результат растровой картинки в файл сохранять не нужно. Нужно получить только файл pdf.

Comment: А сохранение во временный файл чем не устраивает? С преобразованием в файл .pdf и удалением .svg